# How can I use Symfony's Webpack Encore TagRenderer and EntrypointLookup without Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, webpack-encore

I'm adding Symfony Webpack Encore to an existing project with native `php` templates, so without the use of Twig. Refactoring the whole project to Twig is not worth the effort now.

The following Twig code is proposed in the Webpack Encore documentation to render the JS `script` tags and the CSS `link` tags.

```
 {% block stylesheets %}
     {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
 {% endblock %}
 {% block javascripts %}
     {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
 {% endblock %}
```

So I would like to implement the same code without using Twig. These Twig functions use the `TagRenderer` and `EntrypointLookup` classes. How can I initiate the required models and mimic the functionality of the Twig functions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the service in your `PHP` file, then this is the `PHP` code behind the twig functions:

```
$service = $container->get('webpack_encore.tag_renderer');
```

*encore_entry_link_tags*

```
$service->renderWebpackLinkTags($entryName, $packageName, $entrypointName);
```

*encore_entry_script_tags*

```
$service->renderWebpackScriptTags($entryName, $packageName, $entrypointName);
```

---

The arguments u should pass (with default configuration)

- `$entryName = 'app'`
- `$packageName = null`
- `$entrypointName = '_default';`

Comment: Thanks, how do I find the service? What should I be looking for?

Comment: I'm guessing u need to do `$this->container->get('service.name')` in a (symfony) controller and pass that to your `php` template

Comment: This leads to following error: "Cannot autowire argument $tagRenderer of "App\Controller\HomeController::index()": it references class "Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\TagRenderer" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "webpack_encore.tag_renderer" service." - How to set that service or alias it?

Comment: Not sure why you downvote this, if you didn't even register the service on your part